# AutoMapper: Inject custom ruleset for conditional mapping

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have a behavioral class TaskBehavior, that has a one-argument constructor and that drives the visibility of properties in a form and at the same time the properties, that should be mapped to database entity.
Secondly, I have a DTO class TaskDto, and lastly a database entity Task:

```
public class TaskDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TaskBehavior
{
    public TaskBehavior(bool secure)
    {
        NameVisible = true;
        DescriptionVisible = secure;
    }
    public bool NameVisible { get; private set; }
    public bool DescriptionVisible { get; private set; }
}
```

I need to map properties from TaskDto to Task but only those, that are decided by TaskBehavior. The purpose is to have only one parametrized ruleset used to direct visibility and conditional mapping:

```
    void SaveData(TaskDto taskDto)
    {
        var behavior = new TaskBehavior(false);
        var entity = Mapper.Map<Task>(taskDto); // TODO: only map properties based on "behavior" definition
    }
```

The result should be that only Name property is mapped in this case from taskDto to entity (according behavior instance).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it working myself. The idea is to use ad-hoc created MappingEngine instance and dynamically created mappings based on SOME parameter. The whole magic is in the class TaskMappingEngineFactory, which furthermore caches the created MappingEngine-s to a static collection to boost the performance.

```
public static class TaskMappingEngineFactory
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private static Dictionary<Enums.PortalEnum, MappingEngine> _mappingEngines = new Dictionary<Enums.PortalEnum, MappingEngine>();

    public static MappingEngine GetMappingEngine(TaskBehavior taskBehavior)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            MappingEngine mappingEngine;
            if (!_mappingEngines.TryGetValue(taskBehavior.PortalType, out mappingEngine))
            {
                ConfigurationStore store = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
                store.CreateMap<TaskInfoDetail, TaskInfoDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dst => dst.CanExecuteAutomatically, o => o.Condition((Func<TaskInfoDetail,bool>)(src => taskBehavior.AdvancedPropertiesVisible)))
                    .ForMember(dst => dst.CanExecuteManually, o => o.Condition((Func<TaskInfoDetail,bool>)(src => taskBehavior.AdvancedPropertiesVisible)));
                MappingEngine engine = new MappingEngine(store);
                _mappingEngines.Add(taskBehavior.PortalType, mappingEngine = engine);
            }
            return mappingEngine;
        }
    }
}
```

In an "updating" method, I simply add a line creating an engine instance via
the factory. Quite simple, quite straightforward, not so sofisticated, but enough for now;)

```
        var behavior = new TaskBehavior(NopContext.Current.PortalType());
        var engine = TaskMappingEngineFactory.GetMappingEngine(behavior);
        engine.Map(task, updatedTask);
```